# LLVM IR temporaries use

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to find out whether **LLVM IR temporaries** can be **used outside a loop in which they were defined**. For that, I compiled the following simple C code:

```
while (*s == 'a')
{
    c = *s++;
}
*s = c;
```

and like I suspected, the final write outside the loop (*s = c) is done
with another temporary (`%tmp5`) than the one read to inside the loop (`%tmp4`)

```
while.body:      ; preds = %while.cond
  %tmp3 = load i8*, i8** %s.addr, align 8
  %incdec.ptr = getelementptr inbounds i8, i8* %tmp3, i32 1
  store i8* %incdec.ptr, i8** %s.addr, align 8
  %tmp4 = load i8, i8* %tmp3, align 1
  store i8 %tmp4, i8* %c, align 1
  br label %while.cond

while.end:       ; preds = %while.cond
  %tmp5 = load i8, i8* %c, align 1
  %tmp6 = load i8*, i8** %s.addr, align 8
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  ; store i8 %tmp4, i8* %tmp6, align 1 ;
  ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
  store i8 %tmp5, i8* %tmp6, align 1
```

When I edit the *.ll file and manually replace `%tmp5` with `%tmp4`,
then `llvm-as` is unhappy:

```
$ llvm-as modified.ll
Instruction does not dominate all uses!
%tmp4 = load i8, i8* %tmp3, align 1
store i8 %tmp4, i8* %tmp6, align 1
```

Is there any example where a temporary will be **defined
inside a loop** and **used outside of it**? Thanks!

Comment: Note that once the code is optimized, you'll get phi nodes instead of multiple loads. In the final assembly, the value might well be kept in the same register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LLVM doesn't really have temporaries, it uses SSA. That's short for static single assignment, and the key word here is single. Everything is a value and the value must always be assigned *once*.

Anything can use any value which necessarily has been assigned by the time it's used. "Dominates" means "provably comes before" in the error message you got, ie. LLVM sees that the input string is "b", the code will jump straight from `while.cond` to `while.end`, past `while.body`.

When you do use values from within loop after the end of the loop, things can get a little confusing. You may need to think hard and close the Slack and Facebook tabs. But LLVM doesn't mind.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the loop to this: do { c = *s++; } while (*s == 'a'); and then indeed I am able to replace the inner loop temporary with the outer one and llvm-as approves!

Comment: By the way, I guess it's still interesting whether llvm will generate codes like that? (now that we know it's doable -- does it really happen?)

Comment: LLVM doesn't generate code. Frontends do, mostly from third parties, and LLVM copes with it. As I understand it, there's always a frontend that generates that kind of code, whatever you mean by "that kind". ∀ code ∃ a guilty frontend.

Comment: I mean that a temporary is defined inside the body of a do-while loop, and that same temporary is used outside that loop. I'm just wandering if Exists a c program that clang (for example) will generate that for it.

Comment: Remember: it's not a temporary for LLVM. It may be a temporary inside the frontend that wrote the IR, but for LLVM your example is just a value that's assigned in one place and then used in another, after a bit of control flow. It's extremely common. Most or all frontends generate some variety of that, and LLVM handles it reliably and well.

Answer (score 0):

The `while.end` basic block has only `while.cond` block as its predecessor. Thus, you can't access variables defined in `while.body`. It is like you want to access a variable defined in one branch from another:

```
if(...)
   int x = ...;
else
   print(x);
```

Instead, declare whatever variables you need in loop entry block and then use it from both `while.body` and `while.end`.

Comment: Yes, but `while.cond` has `while.body` as its predecessor, so that's not the problem. The problem is that `while.body` isn't `while.cond`'s only predecessor.